# Qt 4.5.3 QEvent::EnterEditFocus

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt docs EnterEditFocus is a event about an editor widget gaining focus for editing but using Qt 4.5.3 the compilation fails with ‘EnterEditFocus’ is not a member of ‘QEvent’. What's wrong?

Comment: Look at this though.  It sounds like this feature is deprecated:  bool QApplication::keypadNavigationEnabled ()   [static]
This function is deprecated.

Returns true if Qt is set to use keypad navigation; otherwise returns false. The default value is true on Symbian, but false on other platforms.

This feature is available in Qt for Embedded Linux, Symbian and Windows CE only.

Note: On Windows CE this feature is disabled by default for touch device mkspecs. To enable keypad navigation, build Qt with QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION defined.

See also navigationMode().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Idan's suggestion doesn't work, note that QEvent::EnterEditFocus isn't defined unless you built Qt with QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION defined.  Refer to the following documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qapplication.html#keypadNavigationEnabled

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include `QEvent`.

Most of Qt classes are forward declared, try adding:

```
#include <QtCore/QEvent>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify QtCore, but it certainly won't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but didn't work. Changing to QEvent::Enter the compilation is successful even leaving that #include out.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following quote from qt documentation on keypad navigation. It sounds like this feature is deprecated or preferably used on embedded platforms:

`bool QApplication::keypadNavigationEnabled () [static]`
This function is deprecated. Returns true if Qt is set to use keypad navigation; otherwise returns false. The default value is true on Symbian, but false on other platforms. This feature is available in Qt for Embedded Linux, Symbian and Windows CE only. Note: On Windows CE this feature is disabled by default for touch device mkspecs. To enable keypad navigation, build Qt with QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION defined. See also navigationMode().

this might make more sense if you are aware that in the source code for the QEvent::Type there is the following:

`#ifdef QT_KEYPAD_NAVIGATION

        EnterEditFocus = 150,                   // enter edit mode in keypad navigation

        LeaveEditFocus = 151,                   // enter edit mode in keypad navigation

 #endif`